# How can I check if VMware tools is running on my guest Ubuntu Server?

Tags: vmware-fusion

I have an Ubuntu 9.10 Server running as guest from VMware Fusion.  How can I check if it's running VMware tools from the command line?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This works in SLES:

```
ps ax|grep vmware
8885 ?        Ss     8:05 /usr/lib/vmware-tools/sbin64/vmware-guestd --background /var/run/vmware-guestd.pid

/etc/init.d/vmware-tools status
vmware-guestd is running
```

You can also check if the vm kernel modules are running

```
lsmod
...
vmw_pvscsi             22359  0 
vmxnet3                44475  0 
vmwgfx                114733  3
vm...
```

Comment: The answer is slightly different if you're using `open-vm-tools` instead. lsmod shows up the same modules. For the running process, you would do `ps ax | grep vmtoolsd` instead.

Comment: These days... `sudo systemctl status open-vm-tools`

Comment: `sudo service open-vm-tools status`

Answer (score 8):

Tested on Ubuntu 12.xx

```
$ sudo service vmware-tools status
```

It works on my machines (from 12.04 to 14.04)

Answer (score 5):

Check that the vmware-guestd is running

```
ps -ef | grep vmware-guestd
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `initctl` to request a list of the known jobs and instances and output the status of each to standard output:

```
#sudo initctl list
```

Note: It's important to prefix the command with `sudo` (or be logged in as `root`). If you don't have root privilages, you could get an error like "`unable to connect to system bus: failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory.`" Which is very confusing.

**Filtering the results**

The `initctl` command might produce a large list of results that flow over many screens.

So, it might be better to pipe the standard output to a paginator program like `less` or `more`.

However, I prefer to pipe the output to a filter program like `grep` like so:

```
# sudo initctl list | grep vmware
```

This runs `initctl` but filters its results to exclude all lines of output unless they contain the phrase *vmware*.

**Understanding the output**

I ran the, grep-filtered, command (`sudo initctl list | grep vmware`) and got the following output:

```
vmware-tools start/running
vmware-tools-thinprint start/running
```

The first line confirmed, to me, that vmware-tools **was running**.

If there was no output at all, I'd deduce that vmware-tools **was not running**.

As [the `initctl` manual page says](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man8/initctl.8.html), each line of output reflects a job's status in the format:

```
job-name goal/state
```

Quote:

> The job name is given first followed by  the  current  goal  and state
>   of  the selected  instance. The goal is either start or stop, the
>   status may be one  of  waiting,  starting,  pre-start, spawned, 
>   post-start,  running,  pre-stop,  stopping,  killed or post-stop.

**Notes**

- For your information, my machine was `Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy Salamander Final Beta`.
- View the `initctl` man page's section on `list` and `status` for more info.
- For the best introduction to Linux pipes etc. it's worth reading those 26, short, pages of that seminal article:
  *[The Unix Time-Sharing System](http://www3.alcatel-lucent.com/bstj/vol57-1978/articles/bstj57-6-1905.pdf)*, by D. M. Ritchie and K. Thompson

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a little help, with images: http://testools.blogspot.com/2013/01/install-vmware-tools-in-ubuntu-easy-way.html
Look at the end of the article.

Comment: Please insert the most important parts as text in your comment when linking to external articles.